# Internet Explorer dies completely on jsFiddle

Tags: internet-explorer, freeze

Just by a coincidence, I've noticed, that Internet Explorer 10 (newest?) dies completly on jsFiddle. Tried on any two [random](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/fHQK4/) [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VXWGG/1/), as well as on [main page](http://jsfiddle.net/). It hangs imeddiately and completely.

Is this browser that far lame or is it something with jsFiddle?

I'm asking just to feed my curiosity, because I stopped naming Internet Explorer a web browser years ago. I call it "Internet Exploder" or "Just Another Microsoft Joke".

Comment: I tested the website with both IE10 and IE11 and I didn't have a problem.

Comment: less than 10 had issues, 10 works for me

Comment: It had to be something with IE yesterday. Now it is working fine. Sorry for making mess. Make an answer from any of your comment, if you wish me to accept it (and get some points).